# CMFCEditBrowseCtrl without button image

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi, mfc

I've created a simple MFC application with a dialog box and added CMFCEditBrowseCtrl control to it with a dialog editor. When I run a "Test dialog" command the control looks like this:

[image]

But when I run my app the control has no button image, like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? The main app class is derived from CWinAppEx, according to the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out that I must include afxribbon.rc to my app to display icons correctly.